# Get previous and next index values in DataFrame should they exist

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Suppose I have a DataFrame

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(vals=np.random.randint(0, 10, 10)),
                  index=pd.date_range('20170401', '20170410'))

>>> df
               vals
2017-04-01     9
2017-04-02     8
2017-04-03     4
2017-04-04     5
2017-04-05     9
2017-04-06     9
2017-04-07     5
2017-04-08     3
2017-04-09     3
2017-04-10     1
```

and a particular date which I know is in my index but do not know the position of, for example

```
cur_dt = df.index[np.random.randint(0, df.index.size)]

>>> cur_dt
Timestamp('2017-04-05 00:00:00', freq='D')
```

Given `cur_dt`, I want to determine what the previous and next values in my index are. Should `cur_dt` be the first (last) value in my index, then the previous (next) element should be `cur_dt` itself.

**To recap, my question is**, what is the easiest way to find the previous and next value in my index (or my current value itself if it is an endpoint) given my current value?

---

My current approach seems rather roundabout, which is my motivation for asking.

```
cur_iloc = df.index.get_loc(cur_dt)
prev = cur_dt if cur_iloc == 0 else df.index[cur_iloc-1]
next = cur_dt if cur_iloc == df.index.size-1 else df.index[cur_iloc+1]

>>> prev
Timestamp('2017-04-04 00:00:00', freq='D')
>>> next
Timestamp('2017-04-06 00:00:00', freq='D')
```

If there's no more straightforward way after all then my apologies. I'm imagining being able to just "shift" my index from my current value once forwards and once backwards (with some nice treatment for endpoints), but am not sure if this is possible.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming that the index is sorted, try to use [numpy.searchsorted](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html):

**Source data sets:**

```
In [185]: df
Out[185]:
            vals
2017-04-01     5
2017-04-02     3
2017-04-03     9
2017-04-04     8
2017-04-05     1
2017-04-06     0
2017-04-07     4
2017-04-08     5
2017-04-09     1
2017-04-10     8

In [186]: cur_dt
Out[186]: Timestamp('2017-04-02 00:00:00', freq='D')
```

**Solution:**

```
In [187]: idx = np.searchsorted(df.index, cur_dt)

In [188]: df.index[max(0, idx-1)]
Out[188]: Timestamp('2017-04-01 00:00:00', freq='D')

In [189]: df.index[min(idx+1, len(df)-1)]
Out[189]: Timestamp('2017-04-03 00:00:00', freq='D')
```

Comment: Ah this is an improvement, definitely more clear and shorter. Thank you Max! One question, maybe : is there any particular reason I should prefer `np.searchsorted` to `df.index.get_loc`?

Comment: @EricHansen, `df.index.get_loc` - might be faster (or not) compared to `np.searchsorted`. I think the best approach is to test it against your data ;-)

Comment: You can also use [Index.searchsorted](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.searchsorted.html)

Answer (score 2):

Reset your index and then use your boolean logic to identify location of your `cur_dt` like so:

```
df = df.reset_index()
cur_dt_index = df.index[np.random.randint(0, df['index'].size)]
previous = max(cur_dt_index-1, 0)
next = min(cur_dt_index + 1, df.shape[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a new timeseries ts with same index as df which will store the previous index (and make sure index of ts is sorted), and then simply shift ts by 1.

```
ts=pd.Series(df.index,index=df.index).sort_index().shift(1)
```

(This might be slower if you only need to find the previous index once, but is faster if you need to do this multiple times.)

Answer (score 0):

```
def get_next_idx(df, current_idx):
    after = df.truncate(before=current_idx).iloc[1:]
    return after.index[0] if 0 < len(after) else None

def get_prev_idx(df, current_idx):
    before = df.truncate(after=current_idx).iloc[:-1]
    return before.index[-1] if 0 < len(before) else None

print(get_next_idx(df, cur_dt) or cur_dt)
print(get_prev_idx(df, cur_dt) or cur_dt)
```